# faster deletion of vector type

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

My question is about optimizing the `vector::erase` function.

Since we know the vector is a continuous memory chunk and also know each element's size in the container, why does the `vector<myclass> v`'s `erase(v.begin())` method still call all the destructors of elements in `v`? Can it do a bytewise shift?

Example:
Say you have

```
//compiled with g++ 4.7
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class barebone{
public:
  ~barebone(){
    cout << "1" << endl;
  }
};

int main(){
    vector<barebone> x(5);
    x.erase(x.begin());
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

This will call destructor for each elements in container (5 times). This will show 5 ones. a bytewise shift will be faster and call destructor only once

**EDIT**: From the reply erase() call destructor once with output

1
   done
   1
   1
   1
   1

Comment: what about nontrivial destructors?

Comment: in that case you only call the destructor of the first element. but do a byte-wise shift for the rest of the elements.

Comment: how would a byte-wise shift recover memory? I'm not following you, sorry.

Comment: Is this a question related to how to delete a single element in a `std:vector`, or are you asking about optimizations in terms of `std::vector` implementations?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp, yes it is about the implementation of vector erase method.

Comment: Watch out when inserting a `<` or `>` in the text. As SO understands a limited set of HTML, something like `vector<myclass>` might not be displayed correctly. Always surround code by backticks `\`` or code blocks.

Comment: This code will not necessarily call the destructor of those elements. The destructor is only called when resizing, and resizing is not required here AFAIK. When not resizing, this will call the copy/move assignment-operators of the first four elements, and the destructor of the last.

Comment: [Live example](http://ideone.com/1xh9Cf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The destructor should only be called for the element(s) being erased; if you are seeing it called for the others, then your `vector` implementation isn't conformant. C++11 23.3.6.5
specifies

> *Complexity*: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements
>   erased, but the move assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of
>   elements in the vector after the erased elements.

Older standards specified similar behaviour, but with copy rather than move-assignment.

Your example shows `1` five times because the remaining destructors are called when the vector is destroyed at the end of `main`. You can see this more clearly if you output something immediately after the call to `erase`.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/646ed396c66ff6ef for C++03 It depends on the assignment operator though. If you use `operator = (Foo other)` instead of `const Foo &other`, the temporary gets destructed every time. Using `Foo other` instead of the `const Foo &other` was suggested in the thread titled `What is the copy and swap idiom` to do some optimisation or w/e.. Anyway, +1 from me. I thought it'd have to destruct all elements no matter what..

Answer (score 0):

I don't buy it.  I wrote a test program, and after the erase the destructor is called only one time.  I suggest that you do the same and see for yourself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class TestObject
{
    public:
    static int counter;
    TestObject()  { std::cout << "constructed!" << std::endl; }
    ~TestObject() { std::cout << "destructed!" << std::endl; counter++;}
};

int TestObject::counter = 0;

int main()
{
   std::vector<TestObject> to(5);
   to.erase(to.begin());
   std::cout << "destructed " << TestObject::counter << " times" << std::endl;

   to.push_back(TestObject());

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output.

Compiling the source code.... $g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm
-pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program.... $demo  constructed! constructed! constructed! constructed! constructed! destructed! destructed 1 times constructed! destructed! destructed! destructed! destructed! destructed! destructed!

Clearly, the destructor executed once after the erase.  Now if you had the erase as the last thing followed by a cout in your own example it is possible that you thought that it was destroyed 5 times by the erase.